# How to create a rectangle with multiple images inside?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

What is the best way to display let's say rectangle (3x5) with icons 20x20 px.? I want to change the image file of every pic icon later (= it's not just static pictures). I tried to make `JFrame` full of `JPanels`, but i was able to display only one panel at a time. I don't want to use `GridLayout`, because I need just small rectangle inside a frame. Any ideas how to do it? Couldn't find any tutorial or solution. I'm completely new to GUI developement. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *do* want to use a `GridLayout`. Your problem is that the `JFrame` you put the icons into uses a `BorderLayout` by default (and really, you shouldn't change the layout of a top level component).

What this means is that, if you add multiple panels to the frame, without using one of the `NORTH`, `EAST`, `SOUTH`, `WEST` constraints, only one of the panels will be visible and take up all the space. If you use a `GridLayout` for that one panel you get, the icons will be stretched, because the panel receives all the space due to the frame's `BorderLayout`. An alternate layout that doesn't stretch its contents is `FlowLayout`, but the layout to use depends heavily on your context.

To display the icons, a `JLabel` is handy. Use an `ImageIcon` for the label's icon. You can later use `setIcon()` on the label to choose a new icon.

overall, my approach would be this:

- use a `JFrame` which has a `BorderLayout`
- to the frame, add a `JPanel` to the frame. The default layout is a `FlowLayout`, which will prevent the stretching
- to the panel, add a `JPanel` with an appropriate `GridLayout`
- to that panel, add the `JLabel`s, each having an appropriate `ImageIcon`